# How to correct excessive lines at the corner and bad line spaces in `polynom.sty`?

Tags: polynom

## Excessive lines at the corner

[image]

---

## Bad line spacing

[image]

---

## Minimal Code

**History:** [This code was done by @localghost at the LaTeX community site.](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=30051#p30051) He made a modification from `)` to `|`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\makeatletter
\def\pld@ArrangeResult#1{%
    \ifx\pld@remainder\@empty
        \@tempcnta\pld@maxcol\relax
        \pld@InsertItems@do\pld@lastline
            {\pld@firsttrue\pld@PLD{\pld@R{0}{1}}}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\pld@currstage>\z@
        \pld@Extend\pld@allines{\pld@lastline\cr}%
    \else
        \pld@InsertFake\pld@lastline
    \fi
    \pld@iftopresult
        \def\pld@lastline{\pld@PrintPoly\pld@divisor\,\smash{\Big|}\kern-2pt&}%
    \else
        \let\pld@lastline\@empty
        \ifx B\pld@style\else
            \def\pld@lastline{\pld@leftdelim\strut\pld@rightxdelim&}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\pld@AR@col\expandafter\pld@PLD
                           \expandafter\pld@lastline#1+\relax+%
    \pld@SplitQuotient
    \pld@iftopresult
        \let\pld@currentline\@empty
        \expandafter\pld@AR@col\expandafter\pld@PLD
                               \expandafter\pld@currentline
                                           \pld@quotient+\relax+%
        \expandafter\pld@AR@col\expandafter\pld@XPLD
                               \expandafter\pld@currentline
                                           \pld@shadow+\relax+%
        \edef\pld@subline{%
            \noexpand\cline{\tw@-\pld@maxcol}%
            \noalign{\vskip\jot}}%
        \pld@Extend\pld@currentline{\expandafter\cr\pld@subline}%
    \else
        \@tempcnta-\@tempcnta
        \advance\@tempcnta\pld@maxcol\relax \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
        \edef\pld@span{\the\@tempcnta}%
        \ifx B\pld@style
          \pld@AddTo\pld@lastline{%
            &\multispan\pld@span${}=%
            \pld@PrintPolyWithDelims\pld@divisor
            \expandafter\pld@IfSum\expandafter{\pld@divisor}{}{\cdot}%
            \expandafter\pld@IfSum\expandafter{\pld@quotient}\pld@true
                                                             \pld@false
            \pld@if \pld@leftdelim
                    \pld@PrintPolyShadow
                    \pld@rightdelim
              \else \pld@PrintPolyShadow \fi
            \pld@firstfalse
            \expandafter\pld@PrintRemain\expandafter{\pld@remainder}$}%
        \else
          \pld@AddTo\pld@lastline{%
            &\multispan\pld@span$\pld@leftxdelim\strut\pld@rightdelim
            \pld@div
            \pld@PrintPolyWithDelims\pld@divisor=
            \pld@PrintPolyShadow
            \ifx\pld@remainder\@empty\else
                +{}%
                \setbox\z@=\hbox{$\displaystyle
                  \frac{\let\strut\@empty\pld@firsttrue \expandafter
                        \pld@PrintRemain\expandafter{\pld@remainder}}%
                       {\let\strut\@empty\pld@PrintPoly\pld@divisor}$}%
                \dp\z@=\z@\box\z@
            \fi
            $}%
        \fi
    \fi
\expandafter\pld@AR@\pld@allines\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\polylongdiv[style=A]{3x^9+x^2-1}{\frac{2}{5}x^4-1}
\end{document}
```

---

## EDIT

See my answer (based on @Herbert's info).

Comment: where are those line corners are seen?

Comment: @Herbert, if you compile the code above, view the output and zoom-in near the top right corner, you will see the excessive lines.

Comment: @Herbert, 400% zoom will show the excessive.

Comment: @xport: this doesn't happen with my code changes ...

Comment: @Herbert, your solution only solves the spacing. Unfortunately, the vertical and horizontal rules now get separated using your setting. They should touch each other and make a GOOD corner. :-)

Comment: @Herbert: Please see my update above.

Comment: @xport: You don't want to tell me that you cannot use 4pt instead of 3.4pt. It looks like that you searched for a length, which shows the effect, but not for a length which makes sense for the output ... However, replace `\Big` with `\big`

Comment: @Herbert: I want to make the two lines (horizontal and vertical) touch each other to create a corner of a rectangle.

Comment: @xport: not drectly possible. Use `\kern-2pt`before `\Big`

Comment: @Herbert: I used `\rule{}` instead of `\Big|`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...    
\begin{document}

\jot=10pt\def\strut{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{3ex}}
\polylongdiv[style=A]{3x^9+x^2-1}{\frac{2}{5}x^4-1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using @Herbert's info, I did some trial and error.

I changed `\Big|` to `\rule{}`. You can see the modification in the part enclosed by `%===========================`

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\makeatletter
\def\pld@ArrangeResult#1{%
    \ifx\pld@remainder\@empty
        \@tempcnta\pld@maxcol\relax
        \pld@InsertItems@do\pld@lastline
            {\pld@firsttrue\pld@PLD{\pld@R{0}{1}}}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\pld@currstage>\z@
        \pld@Extend\pld@allines{\pld@lastline\cr}%
    \else
        \pld@InsertFake\pld@lastline
    \fi
    \pld@iftopresult
        \def\pld@lastline{\pld@PrintPoly\pld@divisor%
        %========================================================================
        \quad\smash{{\color{red}\rule[-6pt]{\arrayrulewidth}{17pt}}}%
        \kern-\arrayrulewidth&}%
        %========================================================================
    \else
        \let\pld@lastline\@empty
        \ifx B\pld@style\else
            \def\pld@lastline{\pld@leftdelim\strut\pld@rightxdelim&}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\pld@AR@col\expandafter\pld@PLD
                           \expandafter\pld@lastline#1+\relax+%
    \pld@SplitQuotient
    \pld@iftopresult
        \let\pld@currentline\@empty
        \expandafter\pld@AR@col\expandafter\pld@PLD
                               \expandafter\pld@currentline
                                           \pld@quotient+\relax+%
        \expandafter\pld@AR@col\expandafter\pld@XPLD
                               \expandafter\pld@currentline
                                           \pld@shadow+\relax+%
        \edef\pld@subline{%
            \noexpand\cline{\tw@-\pld@maxcol}%
            \noalign{\vskip\jot}}%
        \pld@Extend\pld@currentline{\expandafter\cr\pld@subline}%
    \else
        \@tempcnta-\@tempcnta
        \advance\@tempcnta\pld@maxcol\relax \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
        \edef\pld@span{\the\@tempcnta}%
        \ifx B\pld@style
          \pld@AddTo\pld@lastline{%
            &\multispan\pld@span${}=%
            \pld@PrintPolyWithDelims\pld@divisor
            \expandafter\pld@IfSum\expandafter{\pld@divisor}{}{\cdot}%
            \expandafter\pld@IfSum\expandafter{\pld@quotient}\pld@true
                                                             \pld@false
            \pld@if \pld@leftdelim
                    \pld@PrintPolyShadow
                    \pld@rightdelim
              \else \pld@PrintPolyShadow \fi
            \pld@firstfalse
            \expandafter\pld@PrintRemain\expandafter{\pld@remainder}$}%
        \else
          \pld@AddTo\pld@lastline{%
            &\multispan\pld@span$\pld@leftxdelim\strut\pld@rightdelim
            \pld@div
            \pld@PrintPolyWithDelims\pld@divisor=
            \pld@PrintPolyShadow
            \ifx\pld@remainder\@empty\else
                +{}%
                \setbox\z@=\hbox{$\displaystyle
                  \frac{\let\strut\@empty\pld@firsttrue \expandafter
                        \pld@PrintRemain\expandafter{\pld@remainder}}%
                       {\let\strut\@empty\pld@PrintPoly\pld@divisor}$}%
                \dp\z@=\z@\box\z@
            \fi
            $}%
        \fi
    \fi
\expandafter\pld@AR@\pld@allines\relax}
\makeatother


\arrayrulecolor{red}
\arrayrulewidth=0.8pt
\def\strut{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{12pt}}

\begin{document}
\polylongdiv[style=A]{\frac{3}{7}x^9+x^2-\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{9}{5}x^4-1}

\vspace{1cm}
\polylongdiv[style=A]{x^{30}-1}{x^8-1}
\end{document}
```