# File `polydiv.sty' not found. Please Help

Tags: polynom

[How can I get the ordinary polynomial long division by using polydiv like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79411/how-can-i-get-the-ordinary-polynomial-long-division-by-using-polydiv-like-this)

When i came to this link i was trying to compile the codes given in the solution (user:Loop Space) but i met with an error that

Error:
File `polydiv.sty' not found. \ProvidesPackage

Please help me.

Comment: You have to paste the content of the first code block into a file called `polydiv.sty` and content of the second code block into another file, for example `test.tex`, inside the same directory. Afterwards running `pdflatex test.tex` should work.

Comment: Where can I find polydiv.sty?

Comment: The code is given in the first code block of the referenced answer by *Loop Space*.