# Polynomial Long Division

Tags: polynom

`\polylongdiv{x^3+1}{x+2}` using `polynom` package gives the following!

[image: \polylongdiv{x^3+1}{x+2}]

1. The first mark : I'd like to remove the space between the parenthesis and the overline as marked.
2. Next two marks : I'd like to write **x³+2x²** instead of **-x³-2x²**. That is, I'd like to put the product of the divisor and the quotient without multiplying by a negative sign.
3. If possible, I'd like to have **faint** zero co-efficient terms as shown below.

I'd like to get the result as follows. A parenthesis can be used instead of the vertical stroke between the divisor and the dividend.

[image: What I want]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8557/ may answer part of your problem.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209167/different-layout-for-polynom

Comment: Your first question is solved here: [How do I programmatically typeset Polynomial Long Division with connected parenthesis and line? (Possibly using TikZ)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648738/how-do-i-programmatically-typeset-polynomial-long-division-with-connected-parent) and here: [Way to show long division symbol )‾‾‾‾‾‾ in MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867785/way-to-show-long-division-symbol-in-mathjax).

Comment: Your third question is partially answered here: [Polynomial Long Division Using Polynom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63354/polynomial-long-division-using-polynom).  However, the terms with zero coefficients are not faint.