# Different layout for "polynom"

Tags: polynom

The code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
\polylongdiv[style=B]{x^4 - 3x^3 + x^2 + 3x - 2}{x-1}
\end{document}
```

produces the following diagram of a polynomial division:
[image]

However, this is not how I'm used to notating polynomial division; I
usually drag down all the terms and write them in every line, after each subtraction. For instance, I would like the third line to be `-2x^3 + x^2 + 3x - 2` (instead of just `-2x^3 + x^2`) and the fifth line to be `-x^2 + 3x - 2` (instead of just `-x^2 + 3x`). Is this possible to achieve somehow?

Comment: This sounds like a major feature request for the `polynom` package. Have you attempted to contact the package's maintainer(s) to ask if such a feature might be provided?

Comment: No not yet; I first wanted to ask if it could be solved with the current package. Another question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63354/polynomial-long-division-using-polynom?rq=1 shows that it is possible to manipulate `polynom`. But yes, asking the maintainer may be the right thing to do.

Comment: If you are willing to fill in all the steps, you could do the whole thing in a tabular.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155579/polynom-division-without-package-polynom/155609#155609

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, the downside is you must build it yourself...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath\TABbinary
\newsavebox\tempbox
\newlength\templen
\def\rl#1{%
  \sbox\tempbox{$#1$}%
  \setlength\templen{\wd\tempbox}%
  \llap{\rule{1.5pt}{.1ex}}\rule{\templen}{.1ex}\rlap{\rule{1.5pt}{.1ex}}}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}
\tabularShortstack{crcrcrcrcl}{
 &x^4&-&3x^3&+&x^2 &+&3x&-&2 = (x-1)(x^3 - 2x^2 -x +2)\\
-&x^4&+&x^3 & &    & &  & &\\
                              \rl{-}&\rl{x^4}&\rl{-}&\rl{3x^3}&&&&&&\\
 &   &-&2x^3&+&x^2 &+&3x&-&2\\
 &   & &2x^3&-&2x^2& &  & &\\
                              &&&\rl{2x^3}&\rl{-}&\rl{2x^2}&&&&\\
 &   & &    &-&x^2 &+&3x&-&2\\
 &   & &    & &x^2 &-& x& &\\
                              &&&&&\rl{x^2}&\rl{-}&\rl{3x}&&\\
 &   & &    & &    & &2x&-&2\\
 &   & &    & &    &-&2x&+&2\\
                              &&&&&&\rl{-}&\rl{2x}&\rl{+}&\rl{2}\\
 &   & &    & &    & &  & &0
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *really* wanted to extend the horizontal lines...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath\TABbinary
\newsavebox\tempbox
\newlength\templen
\def\rl#1{%
  \sbox\tempbox{$#1$}%
  \setlength\templen{\wd\tempbox}%
  \llap{\rule{1.5pt}{.1ex}}\rule{\templen}{.1ex}\rlap{\rule{1.5pt}{.1ex}}}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}
\tabularShortstack{crcrcrcrcrl}{
 &x^4&-&3x^3&+&x^2 &+&3x&-&2& = (x-1)(x^3 - 2x^2 -x +2)\\
-&x^4&+&x^3 & &    & &  & & &\\
                              \rl{-}&\rl{x^4}&\rl{-}&\rl{3x^3}&\rl{+}&\rl{2x^2}&\rl{+}&\rl{3x}&\rl{-}&\rl{2}&\\
 &   &-&2x^3&+&x^2 &+&3x&-&2&\\
 &   & &2x^3&-&2x^2& &  & & &\\
                              &&&\rl{2x^3}&\rl{-}&\rl{2x^2}&\rl{+}&\rl{3x}&\rl{-}&\rl{2}&\\
 &   & &    &-&x^2 &+&3x&-&2&\\
 &   & &    & &x^2 &-& x& & &\\
                              &&&&&\rl{x^2}&\rl{-}&\rl{3x}&\rl{-}&\rl{2}&\\
 &   & &    & &    & &2x&-&2&\\
 &   & &    & &    &-&2x&+&2&\\
                              &&&&&&\rl{-}&\rl{2x}&\rl{+}&\rl{2}&\\
 &   & &    & &    & &  & &0&
}
\end{document}
```

[image]